# checkbox gridview always false

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

this is my code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" class="table table-bordered table-hover" OnRowUpdating="OnRowUpdating" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
                runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Action">
                        <itemtemplate>
                            <asp:checkbox name="cbSelect" ID="cbSelect" Text="Reject"  runat="server"/>
                        </itemtemplate>
                    </asp:templatefield>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Nourut" HeaderText="NO" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Tgltrans" HeaderText="TANGGAL" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Noref" HeaderText="Noref" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="KDTRANS" HeaderText="KDTRANS" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SRNTRANS" HeaderText="SRNTRANS" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="NOREFORI" HeaderText="NOREFORI" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="NOMINAL" HeaderText="NOMINAL" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="KET" HeaderText="KET" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PPENGAS" HeaderText="PPENGAS" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SNDKOTAS" HeaderText="SNDKOTAS" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PPENGPEN" HeaderText="PPENGPEN" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PPENAKH" HeaderText="PPENAKH" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SNDKOTTUJ" HeaderText="SNDKOTTUJ" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PPENPEN" HeaderText="PPENPEN" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PNAMA" HeaderText="PNAMA" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PNOREK" HeaderText="PNOREK" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PNOID" HeaderText="PNOID" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PJNSNSBH" HeaderText="PJNSNSBH" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PJSTATPEN" HeaderText="PJSTATPEN" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PALMT" HeaderText="PALMT" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PNAMA2" HeaderText="PNAMA2" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PNOREK2" HeaderText="PNOREK2" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PNOID2" HeaderText="PNOID2" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PJNSNSBH2" HeaderText="PJNSNSBH2" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PJSTATPEN2" HeaderText="PJSTATPEN2" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PALMT2" HeaderText="PALMT2" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Reject By Checked" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Reject All" />
```

this is my vb code :

```
Dim chk As CheckBox = CType(GridView1.Rows(0).FindControl("cbSelect"), CheckBox)
    If (chk.Checked) Then
        'carac = "True"
        MsgBox("test")
    End If
```

i try to get boolean value from "cbSelect", but always return false, i try any solution from internet, but still not working,
can you tell me what happen with my code? thanks

Comment: `OnRowUpdating="OnRowUpdating"`, try putting that in your definition of the `gridview` and then try this method `Protected Sub OnRowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    'Get the GridView Row.
    Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    'Get the checked value of the CheckBoxField column.
    Dim isSelected As Boolean = TryCast(row.Cells(0).Controls(0), CheckBox).Checked
    If (isSelected) Then        
        MsgBox("test")
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: you are using msgbox in a asp.net application?

Comment: @JohnKane I would hope it's for testing only...

Comment: Do you mean the checkbox is always unchecked on the load of the page, if so, you aren't setting is anywhere that I see? and if so, what condition should it be set?

Comment: @Codexer i'll try your answer, thanks

Comment: @Ctznkane525 i use that for testing only, to get boolean value from checkbox, when page load chechkbox is unchecked all. i load data from database, and then if i checked checkbox and press button process, i will get boolean value from each checkbox, but now i always get false value when i checked it, i'm sorry if my english very bad

Comment: @Codexer i try to modify your code, i want to get boolean value if i click button xyz (example), i copy your code to action button xyz, but i got error like this "Referenced object has a value of 'Nothing' " it come from this Dim isSelected As Boolean = TryCast(row.Cells(0).Controls(0), CheckBox).Checked